# Binding a property to modelview function in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

### I have:

`userAccess` object:

```
var userAccess = new (
  function() {
      this.userLogedIn = false;
  }
);
```

I have modelview, binded to UI

```
var modelview = new (
  function(){             

     this.itemVisible = 
       function(data) {
           if(data.id === "ID2")
             return userAccess.userLogedIn;

            return true;
       };     

    this.items = [{id:"ID1", text:"text1"}, {id:"ID2", text:"text2"}];
  }
);
```

on UI, inside `foreach` binding I have:

```
<span data-bind="text: text, visible:$parent.itemVisible($data)"> </span>
```

so the **visibility** of the `span` element is binded to `modelview`'s function.

The function determines a visibility of the *current* item based on its `ID` and value of `userAccess`.

### Problem:

The two way binding doesn't work in this scenario. For example if I make `userAccess.userLogedIn = true` the element "ID2" doesn't become visible.

This is because of lack of `observable`, but I can not, seems to me, fit an observable in this pattern.

I know also that I can update binding manually, but would like to avoid this, if this is possible.

I have feeling that I'm missing something obvious here.

[Complete source on CodePen](http://codepen.io/Tigran/pen/njmiB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably refactor your whole setup to use observables. Otherwise, the usage of knockout does not make much sense due to the lack of automated view updates (as you noticed).

```
var userAccess = new (
    function() {
        // It is likely that this value will change, so make it an observable!
        this.userLogedIn = ko.observable(false);
    }
);

// Create a "class" for the items in the list be able to encapsulate behavior /
// properties such as "is this item visible"?
var Item = function(id, text) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = id; // <-- will most likely never change (?) => not an observable
    self.text = ko.observable(text);

    // Use a "computed observable" for things that require more sophisticated logic
    self.visible = ko.computed(function() {
        if (self.id === "ID2") {
            return userAccess.userLogedIn(); // <-- observable = () required!
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
};

var modelview = new (
    function() {             
        this.items = ko.observableArray([
            new Item("ID1", "text1"), new Item("ID2", "text2")
        ]);
    }
);
```

and in the HTML

```
<span data-bind="text: text, visible: visible"> </span>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a89VL/

Comment: ah, ok. I undesrtand your point. You, in practise, refine model view, to even more detailed pieces: so the modelview contains the collection of Item (self descriptive) objects. Will try it, thx.!

Comment: Exactly, it is usually a good idea to bundle things that belong to an Item into a "class" for that item instead of putting everything directly into the viewmodel. That way, every item can have computed properties etc. And you will end up with much cleaner code!

Comment: cool, I managed it by leaving visibility manager function *outside* of the modelview and it worked as well. [codepen example](http://codepen.io/Tigran/pen/njmiB).Thx !

Comment: Niko, the "class" is also a ViewModel ;) ItemViewModel is thus a better name